# B/w movie 1950s or 60s, communist scare, signals are being sent to earth. Religious undertones

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie is from the late 1950s or perhaps early 1960s, and used to be in circulation on a channel out of Boston.

The movie centred around these two scientists who are receiving transmission pulses from our space. It was clever or perhaps I was just too young at the time to think it was bad.

I think the Russian communist scare was woven into the theme as the scientist were trying to get the message deciphered.

I thought Patricia Neal might've been in this movie but now I don't think so.

I would love to know the title.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  It looks like you've covered all the usual follow-up questions, but just in case they help you remember anything else, you might want to check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407).  When you "our space" do you mean "outer space?"

Comment: You say there were religious overtones; was that typical "godless communist" stuff or was there a religious figure or religious consideration explicitly involved?

Comment: Reminds me a little of *It Conquered the World* from 1956.

Comment: I think the O.A. got it (Boss) but I remember another 50's Sci Fi which I did not like that much (not enuf Monsters) about a scientist who invents a Hydrogen or Oxygen or Gold or Oil or Crude Oil--"Valve" which permits him to communicate with "Martians" who explain that they have a method for producing FREE Crude Oil or Gold or something and the Economy implodes. Bad Capitalists or Bad Communists or something. I can't remember if Gort's chickee was envolved...   j.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Movie poster for *Red Planet Mars*]

This is almost certainly *Red Planet Mars* (1952)

Plot (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Planet_Mars))

> An American astronomer obtains images of Mars suggesting large-scale environmental changes are occurring at a pace that can only be accomplished by intelligent beings with advanced technology. At the same time a colleague claims to have been contacting Mars by radio, using technology stolen from the Nazis after World War II. He communicates first through an exchange of mathematical concepts, like the value of pi, and then through answers to specific questions about Martian life. The transmissions claim that Mars is a utopia, which has led to great technological advancement and the elimination of scarcity, but that there is no fear of nuclear war.
>
> This revelation leads to political and economic chaos, especially in the Western hemisphere, and is said to have "done more to smash the democratic world (or Capitalist?) in the last four weeks than the Russians have been able to do in eleven years." The U.S. government imposes a news blackout and orders the transmissions to stop due to fears that the Soviet Union could pick up and decode their messages. This ends when the next message reveals that the Earth is condemned to the constant fear of nuclear war as a punishment for straying from the teachings of the Bible. Revolution sweeps the globe, including the Soviet Union, which is overthrown and replaced by a theocracy, which is met with celebration in America.

(Spoiler)

> But doubts about the authenticity of the messages remain. An ex-Nazi who developed the original communication device prototype wants to announce that he has been duping the Americans with false messages from a secret Soviet-funded radio transmitter high in the Andes mountains of South America. He says that he transmitted the original messages supposedly from Mars, but that the United States government made up the religious messages, which he allowed because he wanted to see the destruction of the Soviet Union. The mystery thickens as it appears the messages may have continued even after the secret transmitter was destroyed in an avalanche, but the American transmitter is blown up before the message can be received.